# Table of Contents for 'Aruch HaShulhan?

Tags: product-recommendation, aruch-hashulchan

Is there a Table of Contents, or perhaps an index, of the 'Aruch HaShulhan?  I have an old set, and there really is no easy way to look anything up*. I'm wondering if maybe newer sets have something, or if, perhaps, someone has independently published something.

<sub>*Edit: There is a short toc/index to O"C only, in the back of the first volume.</sub>

Comment: Isn't it the same as the Shulchan Aruch?

Comment: So I need a Shulhan 'Aruch handy to look up anything in the 'Aruch HaShulhan?

Comment: I thought you were asking for a Table of Contents, not an edition of Aruch haShulchan printed with one.

Comment: @double aa, yes, but one that I can keep with my 'Aruch Ha Shulhan. A pdf printout, or a photocopy, or a booklet I can purchase at my local Judaica store, or...

Comment: So I said you can find one in the front of many editions of Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: @double aa, I happen to have recently purchased a second-hand Shulhan 'Aruch, in fact, but this has bothered me for a while. Aside from that, it's not 100% intuitive to just follow the order of the Shulhan 'Aruch, either. He doesn't make it clear on which Se'if he is rendering his related ruling.

Comment: @double aa, fair enough. A worthy comment, then, thanks. Not 100% satisfactory for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F#.D7.AA.D7.95.D7.9B.D7.9F) might help; it has for all I believe.